# Programmatically update all products to Taxable Goods

Tags: product, import, tax

I accidentally imported 21k products without a tax class id.  Is there a way to programmatically update their tax class without having to reimport again?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a shell script using the `catalog/product_action` model

```
<?php

require_once 'abstract.php';

class Namespace_Module_Taxable extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    /**
     * The value for Taxable Goods (always 2)
     */
    const TAXABLE_CLASS_ID = 2;
    public function run()
    {
        /**
         * Get the tax_class_id attribute
         * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute
         */
        $taxAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
            ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'tax_class_id');
        /**
         * Load all of the products IDs we need to update
         * @var array
         */
        $productIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            // If you want to can omit certain product types, like gift cards
            /*->addFieldToFilter(
                'type_id',
                array(
                    'neq' => Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Catalog_Product_Type_Giftcard::TYPE_GIFTCARD
                )
            )*/
            ->getAllIds();
        echo 'Found ' . count($productIds) . " products to update...\n";
        // Use the product_action for a mass update (much faster than looping)
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes(
                // For these product IDs
                $productIds,
                // Set this attribute id to this value (id => value)
                array($taxAttr->getId() => self::TAXABLE_CLASS_ID),
                // For store 0, admin store
                0
            );
        echo "Products have been updated.\n";
    }
}

$shell = new Namespace_Module_Taxable();
$shell->run();
```

Just save this to `shell/updateTaxClasses.php` then run `php shell/updateTaxClasses.php` in your terminal.

Comment: Nice solution which should be quite fast as you are not saving the whole products.

Answer (score 1):

1. Backend > Catalog > Manage Products > Select all
2. top right you will see Mass Actions dropmenu, select “Update attributes” and submit.
3. scroll down on the Attributes tab and find `Tax Class` and select `Taxable Goods` and Save.
4. Cheers !! All products tax class updated to your desired tax class

Reference : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/38199/